# OpenCV rendering low quality video

Tags: opencv

I am trying to make something like a video player using Python. Quick google search showed me how to play a video using OpenCV. But video rendered using OpenCV is not as crisp as the video played by VLC media player. The images of both players are shown below.

OpenCV rendering

[image: OpenCV rendering]

Video in VLC media player

[image: Video in VLC media player]

I have checked the width and height of the images rendered by OpenCV and it is 1080p. But somehow the video is not as crisp as it should be. Here is the code used to render the images.

```
def start_slideshow_demo(video_file_path: str):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_path)
    cv2.namedWindow(video_file_path, cv2.WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED)
    cv2.setWindowProperty(video_file_path, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            cv2.imshow(video_file_path, frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you set VLC to full screen as well ? (something like libvlc_set_fullscreen() )

Comment: Try it without :  cv2.setWindowProperty(video_file_path, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

Comment: To be clear, I'm not using something like libvlc to play the video. I'm playing this video in the VLC media player. And yes, VLC was in Full screen mode while playing.

Comment: @Ziri if I play the video without full-screen property, the video plays in a windowed frame, but the problem of crispness persists.

Comment: Can you upload a small sequence of your video ?

Comment: Sure. The full video is here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/15uO9i0JwNxi6XQmOuRH6CN0HFKb_7cFh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[image: left : opencv - right VLC player]

i don think it's Opencv issue. I used your code as it is in my desktop.

(left : opencv - right VLC player)

Comment: Can you please tell me your OS and OpenCV version?

Comment: Win 10 - Opencv 4 .